# Transfer iOS app name from one Apple account to other

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have ios app in AppStore Connect. This app not published in the store (only TestFlight). This is OldAccount. then I will work with the application in a new account - NewAccount.

The app has no downloads, I don't need the package id(bundle id), I only need the app name.
Now I have two solutions:

1. Transfer full app from OldAccount to NewAccount.
   To do this, I need to publish the application, now it has comments.
2. Create a completely new application on a new account. I like this option better, but I cannot use the old name. I get an error - this name is already taken.

I tried changing the name. It was "appname" now "app name" (I added a space in name in oldAccount). But I still get this error when create new app in new account with name "appName".

Is it possible? How can I transfer the application name from the old account to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I renamed name in old account to "app name1", then "app name"  became available in the new account. Just adding a space in the name is not enough.